# Cancel Async operation

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, cancellationtokensource

```
private async void TriggerWeekChanged(Week currentWeek)
{
    await LoadDataForSelectedWeek(currentWeek); //Split into multiple methods 
}
```

In case a user hammers on the `Change_Week` Button how can I cancel the current Task, and start a new one with the new paramerters ?

I tried like this:

```
private async Task Refresh(Week selectedWeek, CancellationToken token)
{
    Collection.Clear();

    await LoadDataFromDatabase();

    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    await ApplyDataToBindings();

    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    //Do some other stuff
}
```

**Problem is:**
In my `Collection` I got data from multiple weeks when I hit the button to fast in a row.

Comment: You should paste the LoadDataForSelectedWeek and the cancellation code entire methods.

Comment: I just noticed that your `TriggerWeekChanged` method is `async void`.  Please take a look at the note I added to the end of my answer about that.

Comment: @BradleyUffner that was a mistake I made when creating my question. It's of type `Task` in my code. Thanks to mention !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything that is awaited will need to have visibility on that `CancellationToken`.  If it is a custom `Task` that you wrote, it should accept it as an argument, and periodically within the function, check to see if it has been cancelled.  If so, it should take any actions needed (if any) to stop or rollback the operation in progress, then call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`.

In your example code, you *propbably* want to pass `token` in to `LoadDataFromDatabase` and `ApplyDataToBindings`, as well as any children of those tasks.

There may be some more advanced situations where you don't want to pass the *same* `CancellationToken` in to child tasks, but you still want them to be cancellable.  In those cases, you should create a new, internal to the `Task`, `Cancellationtoken` that you use for child tasks.

An important thing to remember is that `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` marks safe places within the `Task` that the `Task` can be stopped.  There is no guaranteed safe way for the runtime to automatically detect safe places.  If the `Task` were to automatically cancel its self as soon as cancellation was requested, it could potentially be left in an unknown state, so it is up to developers to mark those safe locations.  It isn't uncommon to have several calls to check cancellation scattered throughout your `Task`.

---

I've just notice that your `TriggerWeekChanged` function is `async void`.  This is usually considered an anti-pattern when it is used on something that is not an event handler. It can cause a lot of problems with tracking the completed status of the `async` operations within the method, and handling any exceptions that might be thrown from within it.  You should be **very** weary of anything that is marked as `async void` that isn't an event handler, as it is the wrong thing to do 99%, or more, of the time.  I would strongly recommend changing that to `async Task`, and consider passing in the `CancellationToken` from your other code.

Answer (score 3):

You did not mention about how `LoadDataForSelectedWeek` and `Refresh` interact.

For short you need to create one `CancellationTokenSource` instance that handle every click. Then pass it to that method and do `Cancel` method every time new one appear.

```
private async void TriggerWeekChanged(Week currentWeek, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
{
    tokenSource.Cancel();
    try
    {
        var loadDataTask = Task.Run(() => LoadDataForSelectedWeek(currentWeek, tokenSource.Token), tokenSource.Token); //Split into multiple methods
    }
    catch(OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        //Cancelled
    }
}
```

LoadDataForSelectedWeek -> Refresh (?)

```
private async Task Refresh(Week selectedWeek, CancellationToken token)
{
    Collection.Clear();

    await LoadDataFromDatabase();

    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    await ApplyDataToBindings();

    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    //Do some other stuff
}
```

Comment: `Task.WaitAll` isn't an option since it totally blocks my UI-Thread... That's why I was using `async/await`

Comment: Then I would shoot for global `Thread` and send everything thats in `TriggerWeekChanged` there. Or if you dont need code in `//Refresh Passed` and you are totally aware of consequences in sending those method to other unwaited task, then you can simply remove `Task.WaitAll`.

Comment: @Erexo there's no need for such a *regression*. You can use `await Task.WhenAll()`. Besides, `asynchronous` doesn't mean that a background thread is involved at all. True asynchronous IO operations don't use threads.

Comment: In fact, `Task.WaitAll` would just kill the main purpose of the problem. When executed, Task could not be killed becouse player would not be able to hit the button again becouse of UI Thread block due to `Task.WaitAll`